# MaxHeap implementation

Tags: java, heap

I'd like this to be reviewed:

```
public class MaxHeap<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    private E[] heap;
    private int capacity; // maximum size of heap
    private int numberOfNodes; // number of nodes in current heap

    /**
     * Create a new MaxHeap object.
     *
     * @param heap
     * @param capacity
     * @param numberOfNodes
     */
    public MaxHeap(E[] heap, int capacity, int numberOfNodes) {
    this.heap = heap;
    this.capacity = capacity;
    this.numberOfNodes = numberOfNodes;

    this.buildHeap();
    }

    /**
     * Put all nodes within the max heap in the correct position.
     */
    void buildHeap() {
    for (int i = (this.numberOfNodes / 2 - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        this.correctNodeIndexByShifting(i);
    }
    }

    /**
     * Insert a new node at the current position within the max-heap.
     *
     * @param nodeValue
     *            The node to be inserted.
     */
    public void insert(E nodeValue) {
    if (this.capacity <= this.numberOfNodes) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("In method insert of class "
            + "MaxHeap the element: " + nodeValue
            + " could not be inserted because the max-heap is full");
    }

    int currentNodePosition = this.numberOfNodes++;
    this.heap[currentNodePosition] = nodeValue;

    // start at the end of most bottom right leaf node and shift up
    // until the nodeValue has a parent with a greater or equal value
    while ((currentNodePosition != 0)
        && (this.heap[currentNodePosition].compareTo(this.heap[this
            .getParentIndex(currentNodePosition)]) > 0)) {
        this.swap(currentNodePosition,
            this.getParentIndex(currentNodePosition));
        currentNodePosition = this.getParentIndex(currentNodePosition);
    }
    }

    /**
     * Remove the node at arrayIndex within the MaxHeap and return the node
     * value that the removed node is replaced with.
     *
     * @param arrayIndex
     *            Index of the node within the array based max-heap to be
     *            removed.
     * @return The element that was removed.
     */
    public E remove(int arrayIndex) {
    int changingArrayIndex = arrayIndex;
    if ((changingArrayIndex < 0)
        || (changingArrayIndex >= this.numberOfNodes)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("In method remove of class "
            + "MaxHeap the input node postion to be removed is invalid");
    }

    // if the most bottom right node is being removed there is no work to be
    // done
    if (changingArrayIndex == (this.numberOfNodes - 1)) {
        this.numberOfNodes--;
    } else {
        // swap node to be removed with most bottom right node
        this.swap(changingArrayIndex, --this.numberOfNodes);

        // if swapped node is large, shift it up the tree
        while ((changingArrayIndex > 0)
            && (this.heap[changingArrayIndex].compareTo(this.heap[this
                .getParentIndex(changingArrayIndex)]) > 0)) {
        this.swap(changingArrayIndex,
            this.getParentIndex(changingArrayIndex));
        changingArrayIndex = this.getParentIndex(changingArrayIndex);
        }
        if (this.numberOfNodes != 0) {
        // if swapped node is small, shift it down the tree
        this.correctNodeIndexByShifting(changingArrayIndex);
        }
    }
    return this.heap[changingArrayIndex];
    }

    /**
     * @return maximum node value in max-heap.
     */
    public E removeMaximumValue() {
    if (this.numberOfNodes <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
            "In method removeMaximumValue of class "
                + "MaxHeap the value you cannot remove a value from an "
                + "empty max-heap");
    }
    // swap maximum with last value
    this.swap(0, --this.numberOfNodes);

    if (this.numberOfNodes != 0) {
        // if not the last element
        this.correctNodeIndexByShifting(0);
    }
    return this.heap[this.numberOfNodes];
    }

    /**
     * Place given node position in the correct position within the complete
     * binary tree.
     *
     * @param arrayIndex
     *            Index of node to be correctly shifted to the correct position.
     */
    void correctNodeIndexByShifting(int arrayIndex) {
    int changingArrayIndex = arrayIndex;
    if ((changingArrayIndex < 0)
        || (changingArrayIndex >= this.numberOfNodes)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "In method shiftDown of class "
                + "MaxHeap the value: "
                + changingArrayIndex
                + " represents a node that does not exist in the current heap");
    }
    while (!this.isLeafNode(changingArrayIndex)) {
        int childIndex = this.getLeftChildIndex(changingArrayIndex);
        if ((childIndex < (this.numberOfNodes - 1))
            && (this.heap[childIndex]
                .compareTo(this.heap[childIndex + 1]) < 0)) {
        childIndex++; // childIndex is not at index of child with
                  // greater node value
        }
        if (this.heap[changingArrayIndex].compareTo(this.heap[childIndex]) >= 0) {
        return;
        }
        this.swap(changingArrayIndex, childIndex);
        changingArrayIndex = childIndex; // node shifted down
    }
    }

    /**
     * Switch the node at arrayIndex1 into node at arrayIndex2 and vice versa.
     *
     * @param arrayIndex1
     * @param arrayIndex2
     */
    void swap(int arrayIndex1, int arrayIndex2) {
    if (arrayIndex1 < 0 || arrayIndex1 > this.numberOfNodes) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "In method swap of class "
                + "MaxHeap the input arrayIndex1 is not a valid node position");
    } else if (arrayIndex2 < 0 || arrayIndex2 > this.numberOfNodes) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "In method swap of class "
                + "MaxHeap the input arrayIndex2 is not a valid node position");
    }
    E tempNodeValue = this.heap[arrayIndex1];
    this.heap[arrayIndex1] = this.heap[arrayIndex2];
    this.heap[arrayIndex2] = tempNodeValue;
    }

    /**
     * @param arrayIndex
     *            Index of child node.
     * @return Index of parent to given index of child.
     *
     */
    public int getParentIndex(int arrayIndex) {
    if (arrayIndex <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "In method getParentPosition of class "
                + "MaxHeap your input node position at "
                + arrayIndex + " must be > 0");
    } else {
        return (arrayIndex - 1) / 2;
    }
    }

    /**
     * @param arrayIndex
     *            Index of parent node.
     * @return Index of right child within array based max-heap to given parent
     *         node.
     */
    public int getRightChildIndex(int arrayIndex) {
    if (arrayIndex >= (this.numberOfNodes / 2)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("In method rightChild of class "
            + "MaxHeap your input node position at " + arrayIndex
            + " does not have a right child.");
    } else {
        return 2 * arrayIndex + 2;
    }
    }

    /**
     * @param arrayIndex
     *            Index of parent node.
     * @return Index of left child within array based max-heap to given parent
     *         node.
     */
    public int getLeftChildIndex(int arrayIndex) {
    if (arrayIndex >= (this.numberOfNodes / 2)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("In method leftChild of class "
            + "MaxHeap your input node position at " + arrayIndex
            + " does not have a left child.");
    } else {
        return 2 * arrayIndex + 1;
    }
    }

    /**
     * @param arrayIndex
     *            Index of node to be checked.
     * @return True if node at given arrayIndex is a leaf node; otherwise return
     *         false.
     */
    public boolean isLeafNode(int arrayIndex) {
    if ((arrayIndex >= (this.numberOfNodes / 2))
        && (arrayIndex < this.numberOfNodes)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    }

    /**
     * @return The number of nodes in this max-heap.
     */
    public int getNumberOfNodes() {
    return this.numberOfNodes;
    }

    /**
     * @return The height of the heap.
     */
    public int getHeapHeight() {
    double approximateHeight = Math.log(this.numberOfNodes) / Math.log(2);
    int actualHeight = (int) (Math.floor(approximateHeight) + 1);
    return actualHeight;
    }

    /**
     * @return String representation of elements in the array used to implement
     *         the max-heap.
     */
    public String printMaxHeapArray() {
    StringBuilder maxHeapArray = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < this.heap.length; i++) {
        maxHeapArray.append(this.heap[i] + " ");
    }
    return maxHeapArray.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't checked the details of the algorithm, just some general feedback on the code, API, etc:

1. It's usually a good practice to make a copy of mutable input parameters. (`E[] heap` in this case.) It prohibits malicious clients to modify the heap's internal structure or it could save you from a few hours of debugging. (*Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 39: Make defensive copies when needed*)

   Copying the input array would make the `capacity` field redundant. You could use `heap.length` instead of it.
2. The constructor should validate its input parameters. Currently it's too easy to call it with a wrong size array:

   ```
   String[] heap = {"aa", "ac", "bb"};
   int capacity = 4;
   int numberOfNodes = 4;
   MaxHeap<String> maxHeap =
       new MaxHeap<String>(heap, capacity, numberOfNodes);
   ```

   If you call a `maxHeap.insert("ab")` after that you get a mysterious `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. (*Effective Java, Second Edition, Item 38: Check parameters for validity*) (Copying the input array to a properly sized array could solve this issue too.)
3. It's easy to misunderstood the parameter of `remove()`. Currently it's an index. A client easily think that the following code removes `20` from the heap:

   ```
   final Integer[] initialData = {10, 30, 20, 40};
   int capacity = 4;
   int numberOfNodes = 3;
   MaxHeap<Integer> heap =
       new MaxHeap<Integer>(initialData, capacity, numberOfNodes);
   heap.remove(20);
   ```

   Actually it throws an exception, since there aren't 20 items in the heap.

   Note that there isn't any other method which returns an index so how could a client figure out a valid parameter of the `remove` method? A `remove(E item)` method would be better.
4. Implementation of `printMaxHeapArray` could be replaced with `return Arrays.toString(heap);` if output format is not bound. (Output of `Arrays.toString()` is a slightly different: `[cc, bb, aa, ab]`). Otherwise, I'd use a more compact foreach loop:

   ```
   for (final E item: heap) {
       maxHeapArray.append(item + " ");
   }
   ```

   Checking it again I guess `i < this.heap.length` should be `i < this.numberOfNodes`. I think you don't want to print the removed items.
5. Java already has a `toString()` method. If you use `printMaxHeapArray` only for debugging or logging purposes and clients don't rely on its exact output you should implement (override) `toString()` instead. `toString()` is more convenient for most developers. (*Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 10: Always override toString*)
6. Comments like this are unnecessary:

   ```
   /**
    * Create a new MaxHeap object.
    * 
    * @param heap
    * @param capacity
    * @param numberOfNodes
    */
   ```

   They say nothing more than the code already does, it's rather noise. (*Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*: *Chapter 4: Comments, Noise Comments*)
7. Instead of comments like this:

   ```
    * @param arrayIndex
    *            Index of parent node.
   ```

   rename the parameter to `parentIndex` or `parentNodeIndex`. It would help readers, make the code readable and you could get rid of the comment. The same is true for `getParentIndex(final int arrayIndex)` (`childIndex`).
8. `boolean isLeafNode(final int arrayIndex)` returns `false` when the given index is higher than the size of the array. I guess calling the method with a definitely invalid index is a bug in the client code. Crash early, throw an `IllegalArgumentException` (as the `getLeftChildIndex()` method does). See: *The Pragmatic Programmer: From Journeyman to Master* by *Andrew Hunt* and *David Thomas*: *Dead Programs Tell No Lies*.
9. The `else` keyword is unnecessary here:

   ```
   if (arrayIndex1 < 0 || arrayIndex1 > this.numberOfNodes) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("In method swap of class "
               + "MaxHeap the input arrayIndex1 is not a valid node position");
   } else if (arrayIndex2 < 0 || arrayIndex2 > this.numberOfNodes) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("In method swap of class "
               + "MaxHeap the input arrayIndex2 is not a valid node position");
   }
   ```

   It could be simply

   ```
   if (arrayIndex1 < 0 || arrayIndex1 > this.numberOfNodes) {
       throw new ...
   }
   if (arrayIndex2 < 0 || arrayIndex2 > this.numberOfNodes) {
       throw new ...
   }
   ```
10. Furthermore, you could extract out the checking logic (since it's duplicated, used twice for the two parameters and the same logic is in other methods too) to a validator method:

    ```
    void swap(final int arrayIndex1, final int arrayIndex2) {
        checkValidIndex(arrayIndex1,
                "In method swap of class MaxHeap the input arrayIndex1 is not a valid node position: " + arrayIndex1);
        checkValidIndex(arrayIndex2,
                "In method swap of class MaxHeap the input arrayIndex2 is not a valid node position: " + arrayIndex2);
        ...
    }

    private void checkValidIndex(final int arrayIndex, final String message) {
        if (arrayIndex < 0 || arrayIndex > this.numberOfNodes) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
        }
    }
    ```

    [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has similar [checkArgument](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkArgument%28boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method which supports handy template strings (`%s`) too. (See also: *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 47: Know and use the libraries* The author mentions only the JDK's built-in libraries but I think the reasoning could be true for other libraries too.)
11. I'd use a little bit shorter exception messages, like `"invalid arrayIndex: " + arrayIndex1`. The stacktrace will show the place of the error. It helps debugging if you put the invalid value to the message.
12. I think that the `tempNodeValue` could have a better name. Currently it does not express the developer's intent and the purpose of the variable. (Every local variable is temporary.) I'd call it `oldValue` instead since it stores the old value of index1.
13. The `this.heap[changingArrayIndex].compareTo(this.heap[this.getParentIndex(changingArrayIndex)]) > 0` condition is duplicated. It could be extracted out to a helper method:

    ```
    private boolean compareWithParent(final int arrayIndex) {
        final int parentIndex = this.getParentIndex(arrayIndex);
        return heap[arrayIndex].compareTo(heap[parentIndex]) > 0;
    }
    ```